# Prolog: Export the result of listing/1 to a file

Tags: prolog, export

I would like to export/save the result which listing/1 prints out in the prolog "window" to a text file. Is there any way to do this?

my code:

```
parent(a,b).
parent(c,d).
parent(f,g).

list_items(G) :-
    current_predicate(G),
    listing(G).
```

and the output in prolog which i would like to save to a text file:

```
| ?- list_items(X).

% file: C:/GNU-Prolog/file.pl

parent(a, b).
parent(c, d).
parent(f, g).

X = parent/2 ? ;

% file: C:/GNU-Prolog/file.pl

list_items(A) :-
     current_predicate(A),
     listing(A).

 X = list_items/1 ? ;

 no
```

(I am using GNU prolog if that helps :D )
Thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the stream output to a file by calling `tell/1`, list what you want and then call `told/0`.

e.g.:

```
  tell('MyListing.txt'), 
  listing(A), 
  told.
```

**Edit after comments:**

If you intend to let `listing/1` backtrack through all matching procedures then you may need to split the tell/listing/told across two clauses.

i.e.:

```
list_items(A) :-
     tell('MyListing.txt'), 
     current_predicate(A),
     listing(A),
     fail.
list_items(_) :- told.
```

Comment: thanks for the reply but unfortunately the command only seems to work for the first predicate of the ones in the file. Any other predicates are being shown in prolog but are not exported to the text file. Is there any way to fix this?